# AAPT: error: attribute android:forceDarkAllowed not found

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Im trying to use android dark theme. I install android studio 3.5 preview.

compileSdkVersion 28
 targetSdkVersion 28

but still getting this error. Is this dark theme bug or Im doing something wrong?

```
build.gradle{
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    // ...
  }}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
</style>
```

project link

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DarkTheme

Comment: Have you seen this issue? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DarkTheme/issues/2

Answer (score 20):

You need to up your `compiledSdkVersion` to 29, in you app build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        ...
}
```

Then you should be good to go!

Comment: What if I can't / don't want to use version 29 but stay at 28?

Comment: Then you must not use android:forceDarkAllowed because below 29 dark mode is unknown feature. And how you app behaves when installed on 29 and up? Check yourself.

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for an answer and as [@Ruben pointed out](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DarkTheme/issues/2))

> Changing `compiledSdkVersion` **28** to `compileSdkVersion` **`'android-Q'`** should
>   solve the issue. `android:forceDarkAllowed` attribute was only added in
>   `Android Q`.
>
> Unrelated to this issue, but it seems like you need to also update
>   `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'` to
>   `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'` or the theme switching
>   doesn't work properly.

Comment: Yes, this is correct - thanks for pointing it out. If you don't update to appcompat version, it won't switch themes immediately. You have to restart the app to make the switch.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in android studio suggestions.
for clarification the tag android:forceDarkAllowed is only found in api level 29+
so what we should do is create a folder values-v29 and then write the tag in it like below

in file values/____.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    //removed from here
</style>
```

in file values-v29/____.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I guess that this answer is too new to attract people googling for this issue (the question is two years old), however this was the solution I needed. I need compatibility with API level 26 and increasing it to 29 just to fix an issue with Xiaomi phones is just a no go for me. For others looking to apply it, the names of both files where "styles.xml" in my case, and worked like a charm both in Android 8 and the stupid Xiaomi phone that was messing the dark mode.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error message when I tried to run my previously untouched Angular based NativeScript "Hello World" android application. (In command prompt: tns create, tns run android --bundle)

For me the solution was:
1. Open SDK Manager in Android Studio
2. Install Android 10.0 (Q) (API Level: 29) SDK Platform.

After these steps I could start running my app without any errors!

Comment: I have the same setting still getting the error with nativescript 6.2

Comment: I've done all of the above and still get this error. Surely it cant be this hard. What other gotchas do i need to be aware of?

Answer (score -6):

See the [Nativescript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/dark-mode).

Remove below line:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
```

from file

```
<project>/app/App_Recoures/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
```

Comment: It is a question about native development and people put the line there with an intention.